# Entity Framework Performance Inconsistency Compared to Sql Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm getting timeouts with a very basic EF statement.  I'm simply doing a select from a single table with a Entity.Title.StartsWith("test") and a .Take(25).  When I run this for a search that returns no results I get a timeout.

If I profile and grab the sql statement it looks fine, and if I run that sql in Management Studio it runs in a fraction of a second!

Why would the same query run sub-second in Management Studio and timeout when generated by EF and called from an Asp.Net app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably means you need to rebuild statistics.

This is a common symptom of an incorrectly cached query plan due to out of date statistics.

See this answer: [Why are there performance differences when a SQL function is called from .Net app vs when the same call is made in Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785354/why-are-there-performance-differences-when-a-sql-function-is-called-from-net-app/2785368#2785368)

This will update all statistics and refresh views and stored procs (but be careful about running on a Production machine):

```
EXEC sp_updatestats 

EXEC sp_refreshview  

-- Probably won't need this as your are not using stored procs 
EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'EXEC sp_recompile ''?'''
```