# EF and table valued function performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We're using Entity Framework 5.0.0, database first approach.

I've imported a couple of Inline Table-Valued Function (ITVF) to my EDMX which return IQueryable's. Once returned, We most often do some type of operations on them, like .Skip().Take()

The performance is good, for a couple of hours at least. Without doing anything (at least what I know of) the performance degrades over night.

At first, the query will take around 500ms to execute. Over the night the performance degrades to a level where the query returns a Timeout exception (30-60seconds). This only happens when the table function is executed from code, like:

```
IQueryable<MyResult> results =
            _context.MyTableFunction("searchforthis")
                .Skip(currentPagingPosition*20).Take(20);
```

(It's not just the first time we run the query that this happens)

If we however run the same table function direcly from SQL Server Management Studio, the query will execute in ~500ms.

If I "resave" the table function like:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyTableFunction]......
```

without doing any "real" changes, it instantly goes back to being 500ms fast even when called from code.

Am I missing something obvious, any ideas ?

Comment: Parameter sniffing. [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: do the performance issues manifest with high cpu/memory usage from the app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql runs fast in ssms slow in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175422/sql-runs-fast-in-ssms-slow-in-asp-net)

Comment: @MartinSmith i didn't realise parameter sniffing could have such a big impact? doesnt it normally happen when you have too many parameters in your query? Also isnt it normally linear?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - No it can happen with a single parameter. It happens because SQL Server compiles a plan for the first parameter value passed then caches it and reuses it for all other calls. If that parameter is unrepresentative (say highly selective) the plan used may be catastrophically bad for other possible parameter values that the application passes. Running `ALTER FUNCTION` as the OP is doing will drop the bad plan from the cache hence why it fixes it.

Comment: @MartinSmith oh right I never realized that cool :)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yeah, that seems to be the problem, my example is a bit missleading since I have multiple parameters to the table function, where 2 of them is "fromdate" and "enddate". If the first query after a "sp_recompile" is made, contains a "small" daterange where no results is retrieved, other queries with "larger" daterange will be timing out, since it seems to use the bad execution plan.

Any ideas to how to force my tablefunction to use the better execution plan :) ?

Comment: You can try using [`OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx). Though you might have to do this through a [plan guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895390(v=sql.105).aspx) as EF is generating the TSQL.

Comment: Is that working in a Inline table function? Couldn't find any example how to implement it?

Comment: You'll probably need to use a plan guide. Use profiler to get the exact text sent by Entity Framework.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Will try that, thanks alot for your help, post an answer if you would like me to accept it

Comment: Can you add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to your SQL Statements in your SQL Function?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried adding Option Recompile to an inline TVF but it appears to be not allowed. The only way I found round this was to create a multi-statement function, but they have their disadvantages:

**Setup**

```
CREATE Table MyTest
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY Identity,
    SomeValue VARCHAR(MAX),
    UpdateDate Date
)
CREATE INDEX IDX_MyTest_UpdateDate
 ON MyTest(UpdateDate)


GO
```

**Create Functions**

```
 CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@FromDate date, @ToDate Date)
 RETURNS TABLE 
 AS
RETURN
(   
    SELECT SomeValue, UpdateDate
    FROM MyTest
    WHERE   UpdateDate >= @FromDate AND
            UpdateDate <=@ToDate
    -- OPTION (RECOMPILE) **** NOT ALLOWED HERE**
)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction2(@FromDate date, @ToDate Date)
 RETURNS @retMyFunction TABLE
    (
        SomeValkue VARCHAR(MAX),
        UpdateDate Date
    ) 
 AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @retMyFunction
    SELECT SomeValue, UpdateDate
    FROM MyTest
    WHERE   UpdateDate >= @FromDate AND
            UpdateDate <=@ToDate
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

**Load Data**

```
 INSERT INTO MyTest (SomeValue, UpdateDate)
 SELECT CAST(X.n * Y.n * z.n AS VARCHAR(Max)), DATEADD(D, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X.n), '2010-01-01')
 FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) X(n)
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) Y(n)
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) Z(n)
```

**Testing**

```
-- Index Scan
SELECT * FROM MyTest
 WHERE UpdateDate > '2010-01-02' AND UpdateDate < '2020-01-01'
-- Index Seek
 SELECT * FROM MyTest
 WHERE UpdateDate > '2010-01-02' AND UpdateDate < '2010-01-05'


-- Index Scan
SELECT *
FROM MyFunction('2010-01-02', '2020-01-01')
-- Index Scan
SELECT *
FROM MyFunction('2010-01-02', '2010-01-05')


-- Index Scan
SELECT *
FROM MyFunction2('2010-01-02', '2020-01-01')
-- Index Seek
SELECT *
FROM MyFunction2('2010-01-02', '2010-01-05')
```

Comment: so I try to understand what you meant with this answer, but it's unclear to me if this solved your issue, you just say "they have their disadvantages". I'm having a very similar problem and cannot find a way to solve it.

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza I didn't have the issue I was just answering the question (not my question!). The disadvantages of multi statement functions are that they execute on a row-by-agonizing-row basis (much like a cursor) and therefore are slow on large datasets. IMHO the best option is to write a stored procedure to return your datasets and use OPTION RECOMPILE on individual statements of the SP or on the whole SP.

Comment: would you believe if I tell you I altered the inline function with no changes at all and it did the trick of speeding up? - I guess parameter sniffing is really a pain in the ass when it fails on optimizing execution plan. It would be great to have some control over it, like on SPs