# Query is very slow in ASP.net and Profiler, but fast in SQL Management Studio 2014

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2014, database-administration

I have a MS SQL query that takes about 40 seconds to run in ASP.NET (EF Linq).
I have captured it in Profiler and it shows a duration of about 40 seconds:

[image]

However, when I copy/paste this in **SQL Management Studio** it runs in 00:00:00 seconds. It's a simple `select` on a single table (no Joins, Views, Stored Procedure) and it returns about 10.000 rows.

Execution plan:

[image]

I read [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175422/sql-runs-fast-in-ssms-slow-in-asp-net) witch points to [this blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) and placed

> SET ARITHABORT OFF

above the query in Management Studio but that doesn't make it slow so I don't think that is the issue.

One strange thing is that we migrated the application to a faster server with Windows 2012 / SQL 2014 Web Edition and since that time queries seems to run slower. The same query did run a lot faster on our old Windows 2008R2 Server with SQL Express 2008R2.

Comment: There are a number of `SET` options that can have *significant* impact, and which don't default to the same. The first thing I would try would be to run something like https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/ both in SSMS and via raw ADO.NET (you might need to hack the query to make it friendly, since `PRINT` is a pain to use from ADO.NET, but: maybe just `select @@OPTIONS` in both is enough). See which flags (if any) are different. I will try locally as a check.

Comment: Hmm, checking locally, the only delta is `ARITHABORT` which you are already handling. I wonder, then, if this is bad parameter optimization / query plan generation. If you are writing the SQL yourself, you can use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` / `UNKNOWN` hints. If you aren't writing the SQL yourself: then... yeah, that's a toughie. We have to do that quite often - oddly enough, internally we call this "the Jon Skeet / new user problem" - the layout of our data tends to be massively skewed for new users and massively engaged users like Jon.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for your help. SQL Studio gives `Options = 5496`, but from my application (created an `IDbConnection` on the entity framework context) it gives `Options = 5432`. Difference is `ARITHABORT` indeed.

Comment: maybe you're lazy loading related fields in EF.. if lazy loading is enabled, disable it and try again

Comment: I don't know about the number of records of your table but as I see you have a parameter Date which selects from 1900-01-01, which means a full table scan, except you have a proper index on AppCustomerId. It would help if you could post the table and index definitions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the amount of data in the columns returned was the problem. I narrowed it to the minimal set of columns needed and it became a lot faster. I expect the text-columns are especially slowing things down in the application, however it doesn't seem to effect the same query in Management Studio.

PS. After noticing the performance gains, I rewrote the whole thing in raw SQL and the query duration went down to nearly 0 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the rows have been locked by another action affecting the data you're trying to get but it's not committed yet. Try this for your select statement

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE something
```