# SQL CONTAINS parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search

Is there a way for CONTAINS to have, Column names as both parameters like

```
CONTAINS(cars.brand,COALESCE(@brand,cars.brand))
```

Now if @brand = NULL the second parameter will be `cars.brand` making the query as

```
CONTAINS(cars.brand,cars.brand)
```

which will help me in ignoring the case where I will be looking for a particular brand in a table as in

```
WHERE 1=1
```

and will return the result no matter what the brand is .

But this fails with a syntax error as the second parameter has to be string .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways this is done is

```
((@brand IS NULL) OR CONTAINS(cars.brand, @brand))
```

passing NULL for a parameter that you do not want to filter by.

[NOTE: if you have many parameters you should be aware of [parameter sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server) and the possibility of incorrect cached query plans. Although this might have different behaviour for free-text search]

Comment: Thanks WOW!it worked !so no way to work it through COALESCE ? and how to resolve parameter sniffing or query plans ?COALESCE may be ?because I do have a lot of could-be null parameters .

Comment: parameter sniffing could still be an issue with COALESCE