# performance difference between exec of SP and running the statements

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I am experiencing a huge performance difference when calling a stored procedure with EXEC (with parameters) or running the exact same statements inside the stored procedure separately in Management Studio. The EXEC is 3-4 times slower. What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server)

It's a phenomenon called **"parameter sniffing"** - basically SQL tries to create the optimal execution plan based on what it expects your parameters to be, which is often not accurate at all.