# Strangely, making copies of parameters drastically speeds up SP in SQL Server 2008

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, parameter-sniffing

When running a sproc with SqlDataAdapter.fill(), I noticed it was taking upwards of 90 seconds when running the same sproc in management studio took only 1-2 seconds. I started messing around with the parameters to try to find the issue, and I eventually did, though it's a strange one. I discovered that if I simply declared three new variables in the sproc and directly copied the contents of the parameters into them, and then used those new variables in the body of the sproc, the fill() method dropped to 1-2 seconds just like running the sproc directly in management studio. In other words, doing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
    @location nvarchar(100), @startTime datetime, @endTime datetime
AS

declare @location2 nvarchar(100), @endTime2 datetime, @startTime2 datetime
set @location2 = @location
set @startTime2 = @startTime
set @endTime2 = @endTime

--... query using @location2, @startTime2, @endTime2
```

If I changed even just one of the references in the query body from @startTime2 back to @startTime (the actual parameter passed in from C#), the query jumped right back up to around 90s or even longer.

SO.... why in the world does SQLDataAdapter or SQL Server care what I do with its parameters once they're passed into the sproc? Why would this affect execution time? Any guidance of how to root out this issue further is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: Although I could've sworn there was a difference between running the query from C# using SqlDataAdapter and using management studio, as of right now, I can't replicate the difference. Now, management studio also takes > 90 seconds to run the sproc when I do NOT copy the parameters. This is a huge relief, because it means the problem isn't somehow with C#, and it just a more run of the mill (though still strange) SQL Server issue. One of the guys on my team that's an excellent SQL guy is looking at the execution path of the sproc when run with and without first copying the parameters. If we figure it out, I'll post the answer here. Thanks for the help so far!**

Comment: It would be more useful for us if you put your entire query in your question.

Comment: @See-Sharp -- It seems to me ultimately irrelevant what my query contained. The real question is: why, in any case ever, regardless of the body of the sproc, would using copies of the parameters make a sproc run 10x faster than using the original parameters (at least when the sproc is called from C# using SqlDataAdapter)? Also, it would take some time to sanitize my query to get rid of my company's data, so that's why I'm avoiding doing that...

Comment: can you change from using a SQLDataAdapter and try using SQLDataReader.. this may speed things up.. there are also ways to mock bi-directional reads if necessary

Comment: I believe this SO question will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undoubtedly a case of parameter sniffing and improper reuse of execution plans that were created with a different set of parameters that had a very different optimal access pattern.

The sudden change to the two different-style accesses being the same (rather than one quick) strongly suggests that the cached execution plan was updated to a version that now performs slowly with both access methods, or your data or your parameters changed.

In my experience the general culprit in this sort of small/huge time difference of execution is use of a nested loop join where a hash match is actually required. (For a very small number of rows the nested loop is superior, past a certain fairly low barrier, then the hash match becomes less expensive. Unless you're lucky that your inputs are both sorted by the join criteria, a merge join is rare to find as sorting large sets tends to be more expensive than hash matching.)

The reason that your parameter tweaking in the SP fixed the problem is that then SQL Server became aware you were doing something to the parameters by setting them to some value (ignoring what you'd set them to) and it had to compute a new execution plan, so it threw out the old one and designed a new access path based on the *current* set of parameters, getting better results.

If this problem persists then playing with SP recompilation/clearing the plan cache combined with using different parameters that must deal with hugely different number of rows may reveal where the problem is. Look at the execution plan that is used to run the SP with different parameters and see the effects of different access strategies being employed in the wrong conditions.