# I get timeout error sometimes when I run through the following stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, timeout, cursor

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INVM_InventoryValuationForIssue]
        @TransDate datetime,

        @IssueFrmDocType varchar(10),
        @IssueFrmDocNo numeric(18,0),
        @IssueFrmDocDate datetime,

        @FormType char(1),
        @ItemCode varchar(25),
        @ItemDesc varchar(250),
        @Qty numeric(18,6),
    --  @Price numeric(18,6),
        @WhCode nvarchar(25),
        @WhLoc nvarchar(25),
        @CmpyName nvarchar(50),
        @DiscountAmount numeric(18,6),
        @BaseDocType varchar(10),
        @BaseDocNo numeric(18,0),
        @BaseDocDate datetime
    AS
    BEGIN 
        declare @transnum numeric(18,0)
        --Variables for Moving Avg
        declare @MACumQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @MACumValue numeric(18,6)
        declare @MACumValue1 numeric(18,6)
        declare @MACumValue2 numeric(18,6)
        declare @AvgPriceMA numeric(18,6)
        declare @MAPrice numeric(18,6)

        --Variables for Moving Avg
        declare @FIFOCumQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @FIFOCumValue numeric(18,6)
        declare @FIFOCumValue1 numeric(18,6)
        declare @FIFOCumValue2 numeric(18,6)
        declare @AvgPriceFIFO numeric(18,6)
        declare @TransValue numeric(18,6)

        --Variables for Standard Cost
        declare @STDCumQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @STDCumValue numeric(18,6)
        declare @STDCumValue1 numeric(18,6)
        declare @STDCumValue2 numeric(18,6)
        declare @AvgPriceSTD numeric(18,6)
        declare @dummy numeric(18,0)
        declare @dummy1 numeric(18,0)
        -- Other Local Variables
        declare @CumQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @CumValue numeric(18,6)
        declare @ValMth char(1)

    --  declare @BaseDocType varchar(10)
    --  declare @BaseDocNo numeric(18,0)
    --  declare @BaseDocDate datetime

        declare @TransQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @TransQty1 numeric(18,6)
        declare @PendingQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @InsertQty numeric(18,6)
        declare @Total numeric(18,6)


    --  select @transnum = 1 
        DECLARE SrNo CURSOR FOR SELECT isnull(Max(TransNum),0)+1  FROM INVM
        OPEN SrNo
        FETCH NEXT FROM SrNo INTO @transnum
        CLOSE SrNo
        DEALLOCATE SrNo

    --  FOR MOVING AVG METHOD

        -- Transaction Qty is assigned to Pending Qty variable 
        -- because looping is performed on that
        SELECT @PendingQty = @Qty

        WHILE @PendingQty > 0
            BEGIN
                If (@BaseDocType = ''  or @BaseDocType is null)
                    Begin
                        DECLARE Trans CURSOR FOR SELECT TransQty,BaseDocNo,BaseDocType,BaseDocDate FROM INVM WHERE ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and TransQty>0 and Status is null ORDER BY transnum
                        OPEN Trans
                        FETCH NEXT FROM Trans INTO @TransQty,@BaseDocNo,@BaseDocType,@BaseDocDate
                    End
                Else 
                    Begin
                        DECLARE Trans CURSOR FOR SELECT TransQty,TransValue,BaseDocNo,BaseDocType,BaseDocDate FROM INVM WHERE ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocNo=@BaseDocNo and BaseDocType=@BaseDocType and BaseDocDate=@BaseDocDate ORDER BY transnum
                        OPEN Trans
                        FETCH NEXT FROM Trans INTO @TransQty,@TransValue,@BaseDocNo,@BaseDocType,@BaseDocDate
                    End


                DECLARE MAQty1 CURSOR FOR SELECT isnull(sum(TransQty),0)  from INVM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocNo=@BaseDocNo and BaseDocType=@BaseDocType and BaseDocDate=@BaseDocDate 
                OPEN MAQty1
                FETCH NEXT FROM MAQty1 INTO @TransQty1          

                IF @PendingQty < isnull(@TransQty1,0) -- If Transaction Qty is less then CumQty.
                    BEGIN                   
                        SELECT @InsertQty=  @PendingQty * -1
                        -- Setting Pending Qty as 0 be                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          cause complete qty will be issued from transqty
                        SELECT @PendingQty=0        
                    END
                IF @PendingQty > isnull(@TransQty1,0)
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @PendingQty=(@PendingQty - isnull(@TransQty1,0))
                        SELECT @InsertQty= @TransQty1 * -1                                      
                    END
                IF @PendingQty = isnull(@TransQty1,0)
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @PendingQty = 0
                        SELECT @InsertQty = isnull(@TransQty1,0) * -1                                           
                    END

                IF @InsertQty <> 0 
                    Begin   
                        --FETCH THE PRICE FROM WAREHOUSE MASTER                 
                        DECLARE MAPrice CURSOR FOR SELECT AvgCost from INI1 Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and WhCode=@WhCode 
                        OPEN MAPrice
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MAPrice INTO @MAPrice
                        if isnull(@TransValue,0)>0
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @Total = @InsertQty  * @TransValue
                                Select @MAPrice=@TransValue
                            End
                        else
                            Begin
                                SELECT @Total = @InsertQty  * isnull(@MAPrice ,0)
                            End

                        --FIND THE CUMULATIVE
                        DECLARE MAcumqty CURSOR FOR SELECT isnull(sum(TransQty),0) from INVM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M'
                        OPEN MAcumqty
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MAcumqty INTO @MACumQty

                        -- Other Documents except Invocie
                        DECLARE MAcumvalue CURSOR FOR select isnull(sum(TransTotal),0) from INVM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocType<>'PUIH'
                        OPEN MAcumvalue
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MAcumvalue INTO @MACumValue

                        -- If Invoice Entry has difference amount
                        DECLARE MAcumvalue1 CURSOR FOR SELECT isnull(sum(DiffAmount),0) from INVM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocType='PUIH'
                        OPEN MAcumvalue1
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MAcumvalue1 INTO @MACumValue1

                        -- Entries which are done directly from AP invoice
                        DECLARE MAcumvalue2 CURSOR FOR SELECT isnull(sum(TransTotal),0) from INVM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocType='PUIH' and TransQty>0
                        OPEN MAcumvalue2
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MAcumvalue2 INTO @MACumValue2

                        select @CumQty = isnull(@MACumQty,0) + @InsertQty
                        select @CumValue = isnull(@MACumValue,0) + isnull(@MACumValue1,0) + isnull(@MACumValue2,0) + @Total 
                        IF @CumQty > 0 
                            BEGIN
                                if @CumValue >0
                                    BEGIN
                                        select @AvgPriceMA = @CumValue / @CumQty
                                    END
                                Else 
                                    BEGIN
                                        select @AvgPriceMA=0
                                    END
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                select @AvgPriceMA=0
                        END

                        -- INSERT THE SAME IN TABLE 
                        INSERT INTO INVM(TransNum,TransDate,BaseDocType,BaseDocNo,BaseDocDate,IssueFrmDocType,IssueFrmDocNo,IssueFrmDocDate,FormType,ItemCode,ItemDesc,
                                     TransQty,TransValue,TransTotal,CumtQty,CumtMA,AvgPrice,WhseCode,WhseLoc,ValMethod,CmpyName,DiscountAmount)
                               VALUES(@transnum,@TransDate,@BaseDocType,@BaseDocNo,@BaseDocDate,@IssueFrmDocType,@IssueFrmDocNo,@IssueFrmDocDate,@FormType,
                                  @ItemCode,@ItemDesc,@InsertQty,@MAPrice,@Total,
                                  @CumQty,@CumValue,@AvgPriceMA,@WhCode,@WhLoc,'M',@CmpyName,@DiscountAmount)



                        --UPDATE LINE STATUS    
                        DECLARE MAQty CURSOR FOR SELECT isnull(sum(TransQty),0)  from INVM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocNo=@BaseDocNo and BaseDocType=@BaseDocType and BaseDocDate=@BaseDocDate 
                        OPEN MAQty
                        FETCH NEXT FROM MAQty INTO @TransQty1
                        IF isnull(@TransQty1,0) = 0 
                            BEGIN
                                UPDATE INVM SET Status='C' Where ItemCode=@ItemCode and ValMethod='M' and BaseDocNo=@BaseDocNo and BaseDocType=@BaseDocType and BaseDocDate=@BaseDocDate and IssueFrmDocDate is null
                                select @BaseDoctype=''
                            END


                -- Close the variables
                CLOSE MAcumqty
                DEALLOCATE MAcumqty 

                CLOSE MAcumvalue
                DEALLOCATE MAcumvalue   

                CLOSE MAPrice
                DEALLOCATE MAPrice  

                CLOSE MAcumvalue1
                DEALLOCATE MAcumvalue1

                CLOSE MAcumvalue2
                DEALLOCATE MAcumvalue2  

                CLOSE MAQty
                DEALLOCATE MAQty


                select @transnum = @transnum + 1

            END
            CLOSE Trans
            DEALLOCATE Trans

            CLOSE MAQty1
            DEALLOCATE MAQty1

            SELECT @PendingQty = @PendingQty
        END

        --  select @transnum = @transnum + 1

        --FETCH THE VALUATION METHOD FROM ITEM MASTER                   
        DECLARE ItemCost CURSOR FOR SELECT ValuMth from INIM Where ItemCode=@ItemCode 
        OPEN ItemCost
        FETCH NEXT FROM ItemCost INTO @ValMth

        -- Update the Avg Price in Master's.
        if @ValMth='M' 
            BEGIN 
                Update INI1 Set AvgCost=@AvgPriceMA Where ItemCode=@ItemCode
                Update INIM Set AvgCost=@AvgPriceMA Where ItemCode=@ItemCode
            END
        CLOSE ItemCost
        DEALLOCATE ItemCost
    END
```

How do I deal with it? It does not happen always, only sometimes. Have I written something wrong that it can enter infinite loop? I am not able to understand the problem with it as sometimes it executes instantly for more than 40 items also and sometimes timeout elapsed error just for 1 item.

Please

Comment: add a tag with the DBMS you are using please

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: The DBMS used here is Microsoft SQL 2005 and this procedure is called from a VB.Net Code

Answer (score 1):

If the dataset the procedure is working on varies depending on what parameter values you pass in, you could try looking through the answers here about parameter sniffing: [Parameter Sniffing (or Spoofing) in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server)

Comment: I shall give a try for it. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug it no options , apply logging and see

Thanks
Abhi