# SQL Server Query time out depending on Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a query that uses 3 functions and a few different views beneath it, which are too complex to post here. The odd thing I am experiencing is when running the top level query, having more than 1 search key is causing the query to take around an hour to run, where splitting the query in two takes about 5 seconds per query.

Here is the top level query:

```
Select * 
from  dbo.vwSimpleInvoice i 
inner join dbo.vwRPTInvoiceLineItemDetail d on i.InvoiceID = d.InvoiceID
```

When I add this where clause:

```
Where i.InvoiceID = 109581
```

The query takes about 3 seconds to run. Similarly when I add this where clause:

```
Where i.InvoiceID = 109582
```

it takes about 3 seconds.

When I add this where clause though:

```
Where i.InvoiceID in (109581, 109582)
```

I have had to kill the query after about 50 minutes, and it never returns any results.

This is occurring on a remote client's server running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. When I run it locally (also on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express), I don't get the massive delay, the last where clause takes about 30 seconds to return. The client has a lot more data than me though.

Any idea where to start troubleshooting this?

Edit:

After the comments below I rebuilt indexes and stats, which improved performance of the first 2 where clauses, but had no effect on the third. I then played around with the query, and discovered that if I rewrote it as:

```
Select * 
from  dbo.vwSimpleInvoice i 
inner join  
    (Select * from dbo.vwRPTInvoiceLineItemDetail) d on i.InvoiceID = d.InvoiceID 
Where i.InvoiceID in (109581, 109582)
```

Performance returns to expected levels, around 200 ms. I am now more mystified than ever as to what is occurring...

Edit 2:

Actually, I am wrong. It wasn't rewriting the query like that, I accidentally changed the Where Clause during the rewrite to:

```
Where d.InvoiceID in (109581, 109582)
```

(Changed `i` to `d`).

Still at a bit of a loss as to why this makes such as massive difference on an Inner Join?

---

Further edit:

Playing around with this even further, I still cannot understand it.

```
Select InvoiceId from tblInvoice Where CustomerID = 2000
```

returns:

```
80442, 4988, 98497, 102483, 102484, 107958, 127063, 168444, 168531, 173382, 173487, 173633, 174013, 174160, 174240, 175389

Select * from dbo.vwRPTInvoiceLineItemDetail
Where InvoiceID in 
(80442, 4988, 98497, 102483, 102484, 107958, 127063, 168444, 168531, 173382, 173487, 173633, 174013, 174160, 174240, 175389)
```

Runs: 31 Rows returned 110 ms

```
Select * from dbo.vwRPTInvoiceLineItemDetail
Where InvoiceID in 
(Select InvoiceId from tblInvoice Where CustomerID = 2000)
```

Runs: 31 rows returned 65 minutes

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Have you tried changing that "IN" operator with an OR? Say "Where d.InvoiceID=109581 OR d.InvoiceID=109582". May change the execution plan! But the real way to get help is to post the execution plan of the single ID vs. 2 IDs in the WHERE, so others can analyze the difference and understand why it's that way.

Comment: I had to rewrite the query from scratch. I was not able to isolate anything that was causing the behaviour noted above. The original query still behaves like this, I rewrite the entire tree to avoid the join in the end. Thanks for help.

Comment: Is InvoiceID a varchar or an INT  on both tables?

Answer (score 3):

The Problem you are experiencing is (almost certainly) due to a cached query plan, which is appropriate for some version of parameters passed to the query, but not for others (aka [Parameter Sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211355/parameter-sniffing-or-spoofing-in-sql-server)).

This is a common occurance, and is often made worse by out of date statistics and/or badly fragmented indexes.

**First step**: ensure you have rebuilt all your indexes and that statistics on non-indexed columns are up to date.  (Also, make sure your client has a regularly scheduled index maintenance job)

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "DBCC DBREINDEX('?')"
go

exec sp_msforeachtable "UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS"
go
```

This is the canonical reference: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

If the problem still exists after rebuilding indexes and updating statistics, then you have a few options:

1. Use dynamic SQL (but read this first: [The Curse and Blessings of
   Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html))
2. Use [`OPTIMIZE FOR`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx)
3. Use `WITH(RECOMPILE)`

Comment: Ok, rebuilt all indexes and statistics, checked both the estimated execution plan and the actual plan for a single InvoiceID and adjusted one index as it suggested. The individual InvoiceID executions are now down to around 48 ms each, which is a vast improvement. But the last where clause is still running until I click stop, left it around 20 minutes that time. Thanks for your help so far, any further suggestion?

Comment: Not sure if you get notified, but just edited my question after trying your suggestions. Any ideas? Thanks again.