# ASP.NET SQL Query Hanging on Ajax Refresh

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, jquery

Let me start off by stating how the process of the page goes:

1. Page Loads
2. Function with Ajax (jquery) is called - So the report is loaded on page load.
3. A button allows refreshing the ajax section, not really meant for that but I simplified the issue and removed a lot of things.
4. Click this button
5. Function with ajax called again to essentially refresh the report.

Step 5 is where it hangs.

Now before anyone jumps to the conclusion it must be the code for the ajax function. It isn't, I've trapped the issue down to when I execute the sql query (SQL SERVER 2008)

And here's the catch, this program works, the 5th step works fine 99% of the time. This rare occasion that started this year, that page (on the whole application) decides to say, hey if you refresh me I'll hang on the SQL query.

So I ran the query in the database, it's working (as I expected) and I simplified the page down. Looked at the code over and over...I can't understand why it doesn't work.

The only thing that brings it back up is restarting sql server. Very odd, once I restart, it works you could go 5 weeks and then notice this issue comes back again.

I'm here really just after some insight, any idea how this happens? Like we have this application on multiple IIS Servers running heavy loads and they don't encounter it, just this particular server and only this year (last year...flawless)

So I'm going hey it's the server, must be, so I wanted to escalate it but then how could it be the server when the application is working but just failing on this page.

You could see I'm in two minds and need some opinions to get me in the right direction.

At the time of writing and my investigation I ended up doing a restart on MSSQLSERVER to get things working (for the meantime)

Comment: refresh your statistics.....

Comment: @MitchWheat could you clarify, refresh statistics? I'm not sure what you refer to. I'll give a google search in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362221/sql-server-query-time-out-depending-on-where-clause

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks, this looks good. I'm starting too feel it's to do with SQL Server so I'm looking in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you successfully closing your connection?  You may want to look at your sql calls and make sure they are not locking the tables.

Comment: already checked. open database connection - closed after. sql reader closed after reading. I tried removing end using statement and using open close as well when it went down, made no difference but I will search around for "locking tables" that seems like a good thing to look at.