# ASP.NET Application time out error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Please help me,I have a time & attendance application in ASP.net using SQL Server 2005 as database,The application was wornking very fine for thelast 5 years,suddenly last week,It is getting data for the first query,but for the second query it is taking long time and finally showing time out error

Recently my system Admin updated windows, dotnet & Sqlserver hotfixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebuild your indexes and statistics.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362221/sql-server-query-time-out-depending-on-where-clause).

[Which version of SQL Server BTW?]

Comment: Thanks Mitch,I am using SQL server 2005,It creating a table using bulkcopy methode then that table is binding to a datalist after that i have some colour formating in the datalist say red colour for absent,coral & pink colour for weekenddays,then another colour scheme for leave days.Every thing working fine for the first two operation but if i am checking the next one,the application will take long time and time out error will throw,I check the database,the bulk copy is working fine,but iam getting the error in the binding of datalist..Thanks again

Comment: Thansk Mitch I rebuild all my index & stats,Now the application working fine...It was a great help from your side thanks again...!