# c# timed out exception for simple query.

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ado.net, timeout

Im getting a time out expired.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation.

If I execute the same query in SQL server management its getting executed but trying to execute the query through the program does not succeed.

Where could I have gone wrong?

The query is very simple and its throwing exception.
The time out set is 90 sec.

```
Select isnull(max(voucherid),0)+1 from XXX
dbmanager.executequery(con,"uspXXX",parameter);
```

Comment: if you want help you need to be around to answer questions...

Comment: ...so clearly you don't actually want any help.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your statistics and/or indexes on that table.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362221/sql-server-query-time-out-depending-on-where-clause) answer.

Comment: Thanks but i tried every possible way but still the result is same is there any other suggestions that i can try,,..??

Comment: what is the size of the table?

Comment: @Shaikh Farooque : please address your comments to the original question rather than under this answer.