# Prevent searching logic from executing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to implement a sql query for a search and there are a number of fields that I need to be able to search across but they are all optional.  I have implemented the query in the following way:

```
SELECT --<some fields>
FROM --<some tables>
WHERE   ((@param1 IS NULL) OR ([FirstName] = @param1))
        AND((@param2 IS NULL) OR ([Surname] = @param2))
        AND((@param3 IS NULL) OR ([CompanyName] = @param3))
```

What I am finding though is that now I have about 6 params, even when they are all null, the query takes far too long to execute.

I prefer not to be executing dynamic sql and only adding the sql conditions that are needed based on the parameters.  Is there any way that I can optimise this query to make sure that it is not executing all of the conditional logic?

Just as an FYI, I don't think that the speed issue is down to indexes as I have look at the execution plans and it is running of Index Scans rather than Table Scans or Lookups.

Comment: BTW, does it take significantly less time if you execute the query without where clause?

Comment: @Ali.NET Yeah, it comes back in less than a second without the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like parameter sniffing.

Try [rebuilding your indexes and updating statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362221/sql-server-query-time-out-depending-on-where-clause).

If the problem persists you could add an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the entire statement, or use `OPTIMIZE FOR` to hint at what the procedure should do in terms of query plan.

[BTW: A clustered index scan IS a table scan.]

The canonical reference is: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: Actually [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) seems more relevant here. The OP is attempting a catch all query. `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` should do the trick though.

Comment: sorry that was the link I meant to paste!